# Tracking memory leaks in Ruby code

Tags: ruby, activerecord, memory-leaks

I am not an expert on hunting these things down, but following things seems like sources of the problem and just wanted to check if I am right, and how to deal with it:

All script is basically one big loop, every iteration performs following things, I think could be related to leaking:

1. Mechanize object is used to fetch a remote page
2. A functions is called that fetches or initialized AR object, but this happens on the variable with same name
3. Two more objects are always initialized, but on same name accordingly

The way I think, since newly created objected is assigned to a variable with same name, garbage collection mechanism should take care of this...

## Updated: Simplified version of my code

`runner.rb` is ran every day by cronjob, and it basically spawns list of other scripts - spiders:

```
['spider1_path', 'spider2_path', .. ].each do |spider_path|
  Process.detach( fork { exec "ruby #{spider_path}" } )
end
```

`spider.rb`

```
# This is the main bit
#
agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

categories_urls = get_list_of_categories_links_for_website('a')
categories_urls.each do |category_url|
  next_page = category_url
  while next_page
    doc = fetch_page( next_page, agent )
    cat_page = CategoryPage.new( doc )
    urls_of_sub_pages = cat_page.get_urls_of_sub_pages
    
    urls_of_sub_pages.each do |url|
      page_doc = fetch_page( url, agent )
      sub_page = SubPage.new( page_doc )
      sub_page.parse!
      sub_page.insert
    end
    next_page = cat_page.get_next_page
    # this bit bellow didn't help
    GC.start
  end
end

...

def fetch_page( a, url )
  a.get url
end

...

class SubPage
  ...
  def parse!
    # @doc - result of `fetch_page`
    @parser = @doc.parser
    # do some scraping using @parser
    # accumulate @attrs hash with necessary information
  end
  ...

  def insert
    ad = Ad.where('advert_id = ?', @attrs['advert_id']).first
    if ad
      ad.update_attributes( @attrs )
    else
      ad = Ad.create(@attrs)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed a sample of your code. Trying to envision your code in our minds seriously limits our ability to help.

Comment: Did you consider using jruby or rubinius? With jruby, you also get real threads for free, `gem install peach` and use `['spider_path', ...].peach { agent = Mechanize.new ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried spiking in a call to `GC.start` to manually trigger garbage collection once in a while? I've found that Ruby can get super lazy about taking out the trash under some circumstances.

Ruby doesn't usually "leak" memory, but it can accumulate a lot of allocated objects if you're keeping them cached somewhere inadvertently.

Comment: There looks like there's a call to GC.start in his spider.rb file

Answer (score 0):

You could try using mem-prof or ruby-prof to profile your memory usage and figure out where it's being used.  But I wouldn't bother until you actually notice a memory leak problem.

Comment: thing is, script reaches a point when it is using 3GB of memory, and system starts running out of it

Comment: This is important information that should have been in your original post.